# How Apply CSS for only some Alphabets and numbers by finding them using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am now designing a website which works on local language. I used local language font-face kit for it. Actually when i am using font-face kit for local language English content and numbers are not in good style. So I want to style it using other fonts or css by checking the English content and alphabet throughout the page. Is there any technique in jquery for solve this problem??.. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for us?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier if you wrap that part of the page in a `<span>` tag with an `id`. Then reference the `span` using jquery to change the formatting to a predefined `css` style. e.g.,

**HTML**

```
<span id='localLanguage'>SOME ALPHABETS</span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#localLanguage').addClass('languageStyleEnglish');
});
```

Comment: that i know. But i want search the page for alphabets and numeric without applying class by wrapping them one by one.

Comment: @SinjuAngajan sounds like you will need some `regex` vodoo!